# How to setup MiniProfiler for SQL profiling in EF 5 using ObjectContext?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, asp.net-web-api2, mvc-mini-profiler, objectcontext

I have a WebApi setup and due to some reasons, I am facing performace issues with some of the api methods.
I would like to use MiniProfiler and to test the performance of these API methods and log the statistics delivered by Miniprofiler in to a Table.

The [miniprofiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) docs asks to add the follwing code,

```
using StackExchange.Profiling.Data;
...
public static MyModel Get()
{
    var conn =  new EFProfiledDbConnection(GetConnection(), MiniProfiler.Current);
    return ObjectContextUtils.CreateObjectContext<MyModel>(conn);
}
```

Can somebody help me where actually this needs to be added, how the table will be Created and configured?

**N.B**: I am using EF 5 with Object Context Database First approach(Not DbContext)